# Stop redirection of anchor when clicked in asp.net using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to avoid redirection of link to another if my javascript function returns false.

javascript function to be executed when link is clicked(It checks if flag is set or not):

```
function checkFlag() {
            alert("In check flag");
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            var var1;

            var flag = '<%=Session["hdnFlagInd"]%>';
            alert("flag : "+flag);
            if (flag == "1") {
                $.confirm({
                    'title': 'Confirmation',
                    'message': 'Do you want to leave this screen without saving your work?',
                    'buttons': {
                        'Yes': {
                            'class': 'blue',
                            'action': function () {
                                alert("Yes clicked");
                                '<%Session["hdnFlagInd"]="";%>'
                                return true;
                            }
                        },
                        'No': {
                            'class': 'gray',
                            'action': function () {
                                alert("No Clicked");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }                        
        }
```

Link inside aspx file:

```
<li><a ID="link_Individual2" runat="server" 
                        href="~/Views/Individuals/Individual.aspx" onclick="return checkFlag();">Individual</a></li>
```

The above code is not working for me please help me out.!

Comment: It always do redirection to href mentioned to link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (remove the inline javascript)

```
$(function() {
  $("#link_Individual2").on("click",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // always stop link and handle in dialog
  var href = this.href;
  var flag = '<%=Session["hdnFlagInd"]%>';
  if (flag == "1") {
    // place preventdefault here if you want to only handle click if flag is 1
    $.confirm({
        'title': 'Confirmation',
            'message': 'Do you want to leave this screen without saving your work?',
            'buttons': {
            'Yes': {
                'class': 'blue',
                    'action': function () {
                    alert("Yes clicked");
                    '<%Session["hdnFlagInd"]="";%>'
                    location = href;
                }
            },
                'No': {
                'class': 'gray',
                    'action': function () {
                    alert("No Clicked");
                }
            }
        }
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working if i remove runat="server" property for link.

Answer (score 0):

The `confirm` dialog you are using will not make the `checkFlag` function return a boolean value, because the action functions are executed later and the client is not stopped to wait for a result.

You can try using a Client standard confirm like the following :

```
    function checkFlag() {
        alert("In check flag");
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        var flag = '<%=Session["hdnFlagInd"]%>';
        alert("flag : "+flag);
        if (flag == "1") {
            return confirm('Do you want to leave this screen without saving your work?');
        }
    }
```

Using the [`confirm();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm) function will stop the UI from running the script until an option is chosen.

I don't know of a way to do this without using the standard `window.confirm();` function, you may have to create a workaround to execute some code after they select `Yes` to initiate a redirect.

**Edit :**

See @mplungjan's answer for a way to do this with your custom `confirm` dialog.

Comment: @mplungjan It is sorry, I was writing this as you posted your answer. And you only had that comment. I'll remove it :)